# AutoHotkey - Open html file with Notepad++ then find and replace, then save, close. Include this in another script

Tags: notepad++, autohotkey, shortcut

**1.** In a folder "2" I want to open a selected "example.html" file with Notepad++. Or second mouse button --> Edit With Notepad++

**2.** Then find the word "big" and replace it by "small", save and exit Notepad++ and return to a folder "2".

When html file selected - How a single shortcut key can make the 2 first steps.
Without implementing it into another script.

**3.** And how to implement above mentioned script with this script right before it zips and moves the content to "FINAL" folder. Because one of the files there is html file where I need to perform the above two steps. I suppose the script should start before: "Send ^a ; Select All" part.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass

F4::
for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
try Fullpath := % window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
IfNotExist, %Fullpath%\1\2
{
MsgBox, The folder "%Fullpath%\1\2" doesn't exist
    return
}
Run, %Fullpath%\1\2
WinWait, %Fullpath%\1\2
WinActivate, %Fullpath%\1\2
WinWaitActive,%Fullpath%\1\2
StringReplace, Fullpath2, Fullpath, :,
StringSplit, folder_array, Fullpath2, \,
FolderName = % folder_array%folder_array0%
; MsgBox, % folder_array%folder_array0%
; Sleep 2000      ; wait 2 seconds
Send ^a                 ; Select All
Send, {AppsKey}         ; Press the "context menu" key
Sleep 100
Send n              ; Select "Send to" with the "n" key
Sleep 100
Send {Right}            ; Open "Sent to" with the "right arrow" key
Sleep 100
Send {Down}             ; Select "Compressed (zipped) folder" with the "arrow down" key
Sleep 100
Send {Enter}            ; Execute "Compressed (zipped) folder" with the     "Enter" key
    Sleep 2000      ; wait 2 seconds
    SendInput, % folder_array%folder_array0%
    Send {Enter}
SetTimer, Move_ZIP, 500
return

#IfWinActive

Move_ZIP:
FileCreateDir %A_Desktop%\FINAL
IfExist, %Fullpath%\1\2\%FolderName%.zip
{
SetTimer, Move_ZIP, off
FileMove, %Fullpath%\1\2\%FolderName%.zip, %A_Desktop%\FINAL
Sleep 2000      ; wait 2 seconds
SetTimer, CopyDir, 500
}
return

CopyDir:
IfExist, %Fullpath%\1\2\%FolderName%.zip
return
SetTimer, CopyDir, off
FileCopyDir  %Fullpath%\1\2, %A_Desktop%\FINAL\%FolderName%
return
```

Comment: there are things like `FileOpen` and `StringReplace` in AHK. you don't need to open any external program (notepad) for parsing and replacing file content

Comment: Based on what you are trying to do, it would be much simpler to use a scripting language (**Perl** or **Python**) that replace the content, and launch a zipping tool (e.g. **7zip**). You could also launch this script from AHK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
; ...

WinWait, %Fullpath%\1\2
WinActivate, %Fullpath%\1\2
WinWaitActive,%Fullpath%\1\2

FileRead, Contents, %Fullpath%\1\2\example.html
if not ErrorLevel ; Successfully loaded
{
    StringReplace, Contents, Contents, big, small  ; replace only the first occurrence
    ; OR :
    ; StringReplace, Contents, Contents, big, small, All  ; replace all occurrences 
    FileAppend, %Contents%, %Fullpath%\1\2\example2.html
    Contents =  ; Free the memory
}
FileMove, %Fullpath%\1\2\example2.html, %Fullpath%\1\2\example.html, 1  ; overwrite existing file

StringReplace, Fullpath2, Fullpath, :,
; ...
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileRead.htm

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileAppend.htm

Comment: Thanx, it works!  I have a little bit difficulty to fully understand the AutoHotkey variables and interworking among them. Have tried for some hours, but for more specific tasks it's a headache for me.